# PHP multiple files upload limit

Tags: php, image-uploading

I have this situation: I have a multiple input file but I need to limit the images on database. So I set a limit, and everytime an upload occurs, the limit is checked, but I'm having problems with the loop.

If the limit is 4 images, there are 2 stored on DB, and the user send 5 files, it inserts the 5 files. It must insert 2 and discard the other 3 images.

I need a loop that does that math.

This is my code so far:

```
$prod_id    = $_POST['prod_id'];
$img_limit  = 4;
# ----------------------------------------
$sql        = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE prod_id = ?";
$arrayParam = array($prod_id);
$data_img   = $crud->getSQLGeneric($sql, $arrayParam, true);
$total_img  = count($data_img);
# ----------------------------------------
if($total_img == $img_limit)
{
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
  echo 'alert("You already have '.$img_limit.' images inserted");';
  echo 'window.history.back();';
  echo '</script>';
  exit;
}
# ----------------------------------------
$max_files = $img_limit - $total_img;
$fileCount = count($_FILES["img_file"]['name']);
# ----------------------------------------
for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
{
  $allowed_ext = array('bmp','jpg','jpeg','png','svg');
  $array_ext   = explode('.', $_FILES['img_file']['name'][$i]);
  $file_ext    = strtolower(end($array_ext));
  # -----
  $img_path = 'upload/';
  $img_tmp  = $_FILES['img_file']['tmp_name'][$i];
  $img_name = md5(date('d_m_Y_H_i_s').'_'.$_FILES['img_file']['name'][$i]).'.'.$file_ext;
  # -----
  $arrayInsert = array('prod_id' => $prod_id, 'img_name' => $img_name);
  $return      = $crud->insert($arrayInsert);
  # -----
  move_uploaded_file($img_tmp, $img_path.$img_name);
}
echo "Image(s) uploaded!";
```

Any help is welcome! =)
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a loop for the math? What exactly does not work with the given code?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're applying or using $max_files at all?

Comment: you already calculate the max_files. Use it in the for loop instead of filecount and you will insert just the first n images to reach the limit

Comment: If there are already 2 images on DB, and the user uploads another 5, there will be 7 images. The limit is set on the code. In this case "4".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop is not looking for the limit:

```
# ----------------------------------------
$max_files = $img_limit - $total_img;
$fileCount = count($_FILES["img_file"]['name']);
# ----------------------------------------
for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
{
```

should become

```
# ----------------------------------------
$max_files = $img_limit - $total_img;
$fileCount = count($_FILES["img_file"]['name']);
# ----------------------------------------
for($i=0; $i < $max_files; $i++)
{
```

and even if the user will post 5 images (example) it will load only as many images as free slots you have in your db (limit 4 - total 2 then it will upload 2)

Comment: That's correct. I've tried this and did not work. Now it works. I think I was missing something. Thank you very much!

Comment: glad to help. Please mark the solution as correct if it helps you :-)